# When will an anonymous function be used?

Tags: javascript, function

For example below is an anonymous function that has been placed in parentheses so now the function can be stored as a variable and called on else where as seen in number 2, However how can script number 1 be called to run? How can it be identified if it has no name? And how to change an anonymous function to a defined function?

```
**Number 1**
(function() {
// Do something
})();


**Number 2** 
(var funcName = function() {
// Do something
})();

funcName();
```

Comment: Number 2 is not valid Javascript. You cannot have a variable declaration statement in an expression context.

Comment: An anonymous function can be called later without giving it a name by using a Y-combinator

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are anonymous functions, but they are also functions that are being called / invoked immediately, and hence don't need names to be referred to later.

There are many uses for Immediately-Invoked Function Expression ([IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)), but one is to use functions to establish namespaces that do not pollute global

Comment: yes that's what I thought, but does that mean that they will run once a page is loaded without any input?

Answer (score 1):

The first function is called immediately because it is followed by `()` which calls a function.

Then if you were to remove the `()` from around the `var` statement (which is an error):

The second function is also called immediately, for the same reason.

The value stored in `funcName` (which is called as if it were a function, so will cause an error if it is not a function) is the **return value** of the second function (and is defined by the code you represented as `// Do something` — the "something" needs to include "return a function").

> How can it be identified if it has no name?

Names are only really useful for use in debuggers (where they are *very* useful in stack traces and the like). For identifying a function to call, you access them like any other object or primitive (via a variable, property, etc). A function declaration just creates a variable with a matching name in the current scope.